# VBS with ADODB Recordset Returning "Could not find prepared statement with handle -1"

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, adodb

I've written a VB Script to go through a folder, extract a record number from the filenames inside, query the corresponding zone for those record numbers, and rename/move the files as appropriate.

First I make a recordset of the files inside (rsFiles), and I build a SQL String from those record numbers as an inlist to query the corresponding zones into a second recordset (rsZones). Then I move through rsZones and write the appropriate zone back to rsFiles.

My code works with a small number of files (I've tested and gotten reliable results up to 200) but I need to process several thousand at a time... If I throw too many files at it, I get error 80040E14 "Could not find prepared statement with handle -1." at the line that does rsZones.MoveFirst.

I think this means rsZones doesn't have any records, but shouldn't that mean rsZones.EOF would resolve to TRUE? Also, I have the ADODB Command timeout set at 0, so why am I not getting records on a larger inlist?

Code extract below. Any help/ideas would be appreciate. Thanks!!

```
Const sSourceDir = "C:\MyDir\"

Set re = New RegExp

re.Global = False

Set rsFiles = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")

rsFiles.Fields.Append "File", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
rsFiles.Fields.Append "Record_Number", adVarChar, 10
rsFiles.Fields.Append "Zone", adVarChar, 2
rsFiles.Open

re.Pattern = "(\d{1,})_\d{1,}_[IPG]\S*.pdf"

Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sSourceDir)

Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

If oFiles.Count > 0 Then 

    For each oFile in oFiles

        Set reMatches = re.Execute(oFile.Name)

        If reMatches.Count > 0 Then 

            sRecordNumber = reMatches(0).subMatches(0)

            sInlist = sInlist & "'" & sRecordNumber & "',"

        Else

            sRecordNumber = ""

        End If 

        rsFiles.AddNew
        rsFiles("File") = oFile.Name
        rsFiles("Record_Number") = sRecordNumber

    Next

End If 

If sInlist = "" Then 

    MsgBox "No files matching record number pattern"

    wScript.Quit

End If 

sInlist = Left(sInlist, Len(sInlist)-1)

Const sConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=my\server;DATABASE=default_database;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=yes"

sSQL = "select tablea.record_number, tablea.zone from tablea where tablea.record_number in (" & sInlist & ")"

Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
oConn.ConnectionTimeout = 0
oConn.Open sConn 

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = oConn 
    .CommandText = sSQL 
    .CommandType = 1 'adCmdText 
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    .Prepared = True 
End With

set rsZones = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 

Set rsZones = cmd.Execute 

If Not rsZones.EOF Then 

    rsZones.MoveFirst 'ERROR IS HERE

    Do until rsZones.EOF

        rsFiles.Filter = 0
        rsFiles.Filter = "record_number = '" & rsZones(0) & "'"

        rsFiles.MoveFirst

        Do Until rsFiles.EOF

            rsFiles("Zone") = rsZones("Zone")

            rsFiles.MoveNext

        Loop

        rsZones.MoveNext

    Loop

End If 

rsZones.Close
```

Comment: This code is a mess, you go to the trouble of using an `ADODB.Command` object but then don't build the SQL as a parameterised query. Where is `rsFiles` even instantiated?

Comment: rsFiles was instantiated before the snippet; I didn't think it was relevant since the error was on rsZones. I've edited to add more code.